# Deja Dup gives "Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character" when attempting to restore from backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, 14.04

I've been backing up weekly with Deja Dup in 13.10. After making a fresh backup, I formatted the drive and installed the Ubuntu 14.04 beta. Now, when attempting to restore, Deja Dup asks twice for sudo access (‽) and then later fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1337, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1422, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 697, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 538, in Write_ROPaths
    ITR( ropath.index, ropath )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/lazy.py", line 335, in __call__
    last_branch.fast_process, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/robust.py", line 37, in check_common_error
    return function(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 591, in fast_process
    ropath.copy( self.base_path.new_index( index ) )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 521, in new_index
    return self.__class__(self.base, index)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 497, in __init__
    self.setdata()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 502, in setdata
    self.stat = os.lstat(self.name)
OSError: [Errno 84] Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character: '/media/[user]/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/restoredbackup3/home/[user]/.local/share/geary/[my email address]/attachments/1915/90/\xd0\xc2\xd0\xce\xca\xc6\xcf\xc2\xd3\xc3\xb9\xa4\xb7\xe7\xcf\xd5\xb7\xc0\xb7\xb6\xd3\xeb\xc0\xcd\xb6\xaf\xd5\xf9\xd2\xe9\xb4\xa6\xc0\xed.txt'
```

I'm mostly trying to restore my Shotwell library database, since I have other backups of pretty much everything else. I'm actually restoring the backup to the backup drive itself, since I don't have ~350GB of free space on my internal drive.

Can anyone help me 
a) resolve the error and complete the backup; 
b) ignore the error and complete the backup; or 
c) cherry-pick `~/.local/share/shotwell` for restoration without attempting to restore anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured how to do option **c** above: In Nautilus, right click my existing Shotwell library db, select `Revert to Previous Version`, point to the backup, and done. Did not find solutions **a** or **b**.

Comment: What is option a, b, or c? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @tokam, option c was to restore only the file I needed by right-clicking the current version in Nautilus.